how to remove lpar from nim . tried below commands , not working

nim -o remove bosfleet2-lp27
0042-001 nim: processing error encountered on "master":
0042-037 m_rmmac: the state of "bosfleet2-lp27" prevents this operation
from succeeding

(1) root @ pokaixnim: /

nim -o remove -F bosfleet2-lp27
0042-001 nim: processing error encountered on "master":
0042-037 m_rmmac: the state of "bosfleet2-lp27" prevents this operation
from succeeding

these above commands i tried . i need to remove this lpar or reset this lpar ..both are not working

nim -Fo reset bosfleet2-lp27
0042-001 nim: processing error encountered on "master":
0042-027 m_abort: "if1" is required to complete the
definition of the "bosfleet2-lp27" object.  This attribute is either
currently missing or the current operation would cause
it to become missing


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
